# OpenStreetMaps: what are the !pixel_width! and !pixel_height! in the queries

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap

The Github repository containing the CartoCSS styling for the OpenStreetMaps dataset also defines queries for the different layers (see [this file](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/blob/master/project.yaml)).

An example of such a query is

```
SELECT
    way,
    "natural",
    waterway,
    landuse,
    name,
    way_area/NULLIF(!pixel_width!::real*!pixel_height!::real,0) AS way_pixels
  FROM planet_osm_polygon
  WHERE
    (waterway IN ('dock', 'riverbank', 'canal')
      OR landuse IN ('reservoir', 'basin')
      OR "natural" IN ('water', 'glacier'))
    AND building IS NULL
    AND way_area > 0.01*!pixel_width!::real*!pixel_height!::real
  ORDER BY z_order, way_area DESC
```

Running this query against my local database fails with

```
ERROR:  column "pixel_width" does not exist
LINE 7:             way_area/NULLIF(!pixel_width!::real*!pixel_heigh...
```

as error message. This is on Ubuntu where `psql --version` outputs

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.10
```

Anybody has any idea what those `pixel_width` and `pixel_height` values are, and what I need to do with my local PostGIS database to run those queries ? The steps on the [OpenStreetMap Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PostGIS) do not list anything special.

The closest match I found is the [`ST_PixelWidth` function](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_PixelWidth.html) but this is for rasters, and the syntax used in the examples does not match the syntax used in OSM. So it is obviously not that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to switch to Mapnik 2.1.0 if you want to use this style. See https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/PostGIS#other-tokens.

At this point the size of a way relative to the pixel is calculated, and the way will get dropped if it is too small. See also https://github.com/mapbox/osm-bright/issues/72 for a suggestion on the OSM Bright style, and how it can be substituted.

Comment: Are you saying that the queries present in that file are not directly send to the PostGIS database, but that those are queries interpreted and converted by Mapnik before they are send to the database ?

Comment: Yes, see https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/blob/2.1.x/plugins/input/postgis/postgis_datasource.cpp